# telnet Connection closed when I use yield in diesel

Tags: python, chat

hi I want to create chat server with [diesel](http://diesel.io) . I use this code for running [simple chat server](https://bitbucket.org/sjl/diesel/src/4f9dff1bb14679d55f96d46dc58c7543d39b5174/examples/chat.py?at=default)  :

```
from diesel import Application, Service, until_eol, fire, wait

def chat_server(addr):
    my_nick = (yield until_eol()).strip()
    while True:
        my_message, other_message = yield (until_eol(), wait('chat_message'))
        if my_message:
            yield fire('chat_message', (my_nick, my_message.strip()))
        else:
            nick, message = other_message
            yield "<%s> %s\r\n"  % (nick, message)

app = Application()
app.add_service(Service(chat_server, 8000))
app.run()
```

but when I try to telnet this server , telnet Connection closed by foreign host.

```
[nima@ca005 Desktop]$ telnet localhost 8000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

when I remove yield from code I have no problem with connectiong to server.

```
def chat_server(addr):
    my_nick = until_eol().strip()
    while True:
        message = diesel.until_eol()
        shouted_message = my_nick + ":" + message
        diesel.send(shouted_message)
        my_message = until_eol()
        other_message = wait('chat_message')
        if my_message:
            fire('chat_message', (my_nick, my_message.strip()))
```

what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Does the process waiting on "message = diesel.until_eol()" keep the connection alive? Maybe you might want to use threads in place of co-rountines (as in a server message accumulation thread and a client message accumulation/server message processing thread).

Comment: yes It keep the connection alive. can you give me an example of using thread in this code?

Comment: diesel dropped the `yield` syntax a while ago. It now uses greenlets behind the scenes. The accepted answer below (from the diesel examples, I think) is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right code [here](https://github.com/jamwt/diesel/issues/77) :

```
# vim:ts=4:sw=4:expandtab
'''Simple chat server.

telnet, type your name, hit enter, then chat.  Invite
a friend to do the same.
'''
from diesel import Application, Service, until_eol, fire, first, send

def chat_server(addr):
    my_nick = until_eol().strip()
    while True:
        evt, data = first(until_eol=True, waits=['chat_message'])
        if evt == 'until_eol':
           fire('chat_message', (my_nick, data.strip()))
        else:
            nick, message = data
            send("<%s> %s\r\n"  % (nick, message))

app = Application()
app.add_service(Service(chat_server, 8000))
app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this. It mightn't work straight away as I am unfamiliar with how diesel works.

```
import StringIO
import socket
import threading

from diesel import Application, Service, until_eol, fire, wait

class socket_thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, line_filter = None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.event = threading.Event()
        self.event.clear()
        self.buffer = StringIO.StringIO()
        if(line_filter == None):
            self.line_filter = lambda x: x
        else:
            self.line_filter = line_filter

    def run(self):
        message = True
        while message:
            message = diesel.until_eol()

            self.lock.acquire()
            self.buffer.write(message)
            self.lock.release()
            self.event.set()

    def readlines(self):
        self.lock.acquire()

        self.buffer.seek(0)
        raw_lines = self.buffer.readlines()
        self.buffer.truncate(0)

        self.lock.release()

        lines = map(self.line_filter, raw_lines)
        return lines

def chat_server(addr):
    server_recv = socket_thread()
    my_nick = until_eol().strip()
    data = []
    server_recv.start()
    while True:
        server_recv.event.wait()
        data = server_recv.readlines()
        if(data):
            shouted_message = my_nick + ":" + data
            diesel.send(shouted_message)
        server_recv.event.clear()

        my_message = until_eol()
        other_message = wait('chat_message')
        if my_message:
            fire('chat_message', (my_nick, my_message.strip()))

app = Application()
app.add_service(Service(chat_server, 8000))
app.run()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I found the right code [here](https://github.com/jamwt/diesel/issues/77)

Comment: Should probably post that as an answer to this question.